# Live reload not working with @angular/cli when using AOT (--aot) with ngserve

Tags: angular, angular-cli, livereload

I just found out that live reload is not working in combination with AOT.

```
Not working:   ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
Working:       ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

I wonder why? For example, I changed some markup in an HTML template; @angular/cli is processing (compiling, etc.) my change, also a browser reload is forced, but the change has no effect.

I use NgModules in my app (shared module, etc.) but no lazy loading.

ng -v:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.2
node: 6.10.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.1.1
@angular/compiler: 4.1.1
@angular/core: 4.1.1
@angular/forms: 4.1.1
@angular/http: 4.1.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.1
@angular/router: 4.1.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.1
```

In my opinion this is a major issue, because my code might run locally, but not on the build machine, where I use AOT. Also, working without live reload is super tiresome.

Is there a way to get ng serve with AOT and live reload properly running?